# Matplotlib: draw a contour to an axis after the contour has been created

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I added contour plot to an axis. Now I want to draw the same contour on the other axes without recreating the contour (because creating the contour can be quite involved). I saved the contour created by the function as `CS`. Is there a way to redraw that same contour on all the other axes?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

def draw_contour():
    delta = 0.025
    x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
    y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
    # difference of Gaussians
    Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
    C = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, linewidth=2, colors='k')
    return C

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)
plt.sca(ax1)
CS = draw_contour()
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)

plt.sca(ax2)
# redraw CS

plt.sca(ax3)
# redraw CS

plt.sca(ax3)
# redraw CS
```

[image]

If this can be done, how can I do the same thing for plt.pcolormesh() and plt.scatter()

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workable approach. You can copy the contents of the `Axes` with the contour plot to the other `Axes`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

def draw_contour(ax):
    delta = 0.025
    x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
    y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
    # difference of Gaussians
    Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
    C = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='k')
    return C

# dfix is a hack to fix dashing size in copied lines. May need to adjust
def copy_linecollection(x, axdst, dfix=1.5):
    ls = [(ls[0], (ls[1][0]/dfix, ls[1][1]/dfix)) if ls[0] is not None else ls for ls in x.get_linestyles()]

    axdst.add_collection(mpl.collections.LineCollection(
        [p.vertices for p in x.get_paths()],
        linewidths=x.get_linewidths(), 
        colors=x.get_colors(),
        linestyles=ls,
    ))

def copy_text(x, axdst):
    axdst.text(
        *x.get_position(), 
        s=x.get_text(),
        color=x.get_color(), 
        verticalalignment=x.get_verticalalignment(), 
        horizontalalignment=x.get_horizontalalignment(), 
        fontproperties=x.get_fontproperties(), 
        rotation=x.get_rotation(),
        clip_box=axdst.get_position(),
        clip_on=True
    )

def copy_ax(axsrc, axdst):
    for c in axsrc.get_children():
        if isinstance(c, mpl.collections.LineCollection):
            copy_linecollection(c, axdst)

        elif isinstance(c, mpl.text.Text) and c.get_text():
            copy_text(c, axdst)

subplots_kw = {
    'sharex': True, 
    'sharey': True, 
    'figsize': (10,10),
    'gridspec_kw': {
        'hspace': 0,
        'wspace': 0
    }
}
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, **subplots_kw)

CS = draw_contour(ax1)
ax1.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)

for ax in (ax2,ax3,ax4):
    copy_ax(ax1, ax)
```

Output:

[image]

This approach won't work for other types of plots as-is (or even all `contour` plots, necessarily), but it can be generalized. You would need to run, for example, `ax.scatter(...)` and then look through the contents of the list returned by `ax.get_children()`. You would then need to write `copy_x` functions for all of the different types present in the children list and update `copy_ax` to incorporate those new copy functions.

## Edit

Came up with a simpler, more general version of `copy_ax`:

```
from copy import copy as shallowcopy

def copy_artist(x, axdst):
    xc = shallowcopy(x)
    xc.axes = None
    xc.figure = None
    xc.set_transform(axdst.transData)
    axdst.add_artist(xc)

def copy_ax(axsrc, *axdsts):
    for axdst in axdsts:
        # don't need the last 10 items (frame, spines, etc) in get_children
        for c in axsrc.get_children()[:-10]:
            copy_artist(c, axdst)
```

This version of `copy_ax` works well with the results from many different plotting functions (`plt.plot`, for example)... but sadly not `plt.scatter` or `plt.pcolormesh`. I actually now don't think that this or my previous approach can work with either of those. As an alternative for `scatter`, at least, you can just make scatter plots using `plot`:

```
def draw_scatter(ax):
    x = np.random.uniform(-2,2,size=100)
    y = np.random.uniform(-2,2,size=100)
    return ax.plot(x,y,ls='none',marker='.')

subplots_kw = {
    'sharex': True, 
    'sharey': True, 
    'figsize': (10,10),
    'gridspec_kw': {
        'hspace': 0,
        'wspace': 0
    }
}
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, **subplots_kw)

draw_scatter(ax1)
copy_ax(ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4)
```

Output:

[image]